# Exporting component using i18n's useTranslation and redux's connect HOCs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, i18next

My App has used Redux for a long time, with the component exports looking like

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```

I'm now introducing i18n's translation library and would like to use the HOC that is included with the `useTranslation`.

I've attempted a few different ways and seen that `Redux` has a `connect` piece of functionality that is supposed to combine HOCs if I understand correctly, however I cannot get this to work.

```
export default connect(useTranslation(), connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps))(MyComponent);
```

When I load the browser I am shown:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useTranslation` is not a HOC, you want `withTranslation`. That will look like this:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withTranslation()(MyComponent));
```

Or, since the order doesn't matter:

```
export default withTranslation()(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent));
```

Nesting multiple HOCs can be hard to read, so it may be easier to use a `compose` utility function. Redux even includes one:

```
import { compose, connect } from 'redux';

//...

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
  withTranslation()
)(MyComponent);
```

Comment: AH! My mistake not reading properly. `with` not `use`. I must have been confusing myself as I was using `const {t} = useTranslation()` before.